# player.sendMessage sends twice

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

After right clicking with shrooms, it says "You consumed shrooms", then after trying again it says "Don't overdose, kids", but if consuming Sugar it tells you "You snorted cocaine" "Don't overdose, kids" instantly. What seems to be the problem?

I have tried seperate classes, also when doing sendMessage on right click it double right clicks if consuming sugar.

Events class

```
package com.maverick.drugPlugin.Events;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;


public class EventsClass implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
    public void consumeDrugs(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        Action action = event.getAction();

        if(action.equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) || action.equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
            if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.BROWN_MUSHROOM) {
                if(!player.hasPotionEffect(PotionEffectType.CONFUSION)) {
                player.getInventory().getItemInHand().setAmount(player.getInventory().getItemInHand().getAmount() - 1);
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You consumed " + ChatColor.BLUE + "shrooms");
                player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.CONFUSION, 120*20, 1, true, false));
                } else {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Don't overdose, kids");
            }
    }
}
        if(action.equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) || action.equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
            if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.SUGAR) {
                if(!player.hasPotionEffect(PotionEffectType.CONFUSION)) {
                player.getInventory().getItemInHand().setAmount(player.getInventory().getItemInHand().getAmount() - 1);
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You snorted " + ChatColor.BLUE + "cocaine");
                player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.CONFUSION, 120*20, 1, true, false));
                } else {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Don't overdose, kids");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.maverick.drugPlugin;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import com.maverick.drugPlugin.Events.EventsClass;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;

public class Drugs extends JavaPlugin {

    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new EventsClass(), this);
        getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "\n\nDrugs are enabled\n\n");
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "\n\nDrugs are Disabled\n\n");
    }
}
```

I want so that when consuming Sugar (Cocaine) it says first "You snorted cocaine" and then trying to consume again it would tell you "Don't overdose, kids" like on shrooms.

Comment: I tried everything and i can't seem to find a problem. I tried different classes, tried registering the clicks and it showed that it registers the clicks twice on consuming sugar. I can't figure out how to stop that

Comment: Well there you have it. It registers the click twice, thats the problem! Maybe you found a bug in minecraft! There is nothing wrong in the code above, not counting the IF-statements.

Comment: Yeah, i found out i can debug if it calls twice. I am now discussing with people on why it does that. Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: Which version are you using? Because in 1.13.2 this code works perfectly.

Comment: Also `getItemInHand()` is deprecated, use `getInventory().getItemInMainHand()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The PlayerInteract event can be a bit temperamental and will sometimes fire, once, twice or even multiple times. In cases like this a solution I used in the past was to use a `Map<UUID, Long>` to store the current timestamp `System.currentTimeMillis()` of when the player triggered the interact event.

Then with a bit of testing, and depending on the behaviour you are after if subsequent interact events occur within a short time window, say 100-200 ms then you can just discard them and that would resolve your double click issue.